# how we crop image at front end from wordpress classiads theme

Tags: wordpress, image-processing

I purchase a classiads template of wordpress.
everything work is fine but i stuck at one point. i wish when i submit a post from front end as a user then image automatically crop 600 * 400 size. i apply different plugin but still image size not change.
Please guide what i am doing.

Below post i attach post page screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a plugin then try this one out. It will give you a custom button to crop and upload the image.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-regenerate-select-crop/

Comment: thanku but i do not understand how it will work with front end there is no more settings

Comment: Can you please check this link. There are some doc and UI gallery available that will be helpful http://www.wpmeta.org/plugins/image-regenerate-select-crop/